# Vector and Function in R programming

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a function below that gets me a square root of a number. However, I have a vector I'm trying to pass in, but it only takes the first element and gives me an output of "not possible". Does anyone have any ideas what I can do for this function to take my second number and gives me an output of "not possible not possible". Thank you!

```
getRootNotVectorized <- function(x){
    if(x<0)
        return("not possible") else
            return( sqrt(x))
}

getRootNotVectorized(c(-1, -4))
[1] "not possible"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could vectorize it:

```
getRootVectorized <- Vectorize(getRootNotVectorized)
getRootVectorized(c(-1, -4))
# [1] "not possible" "not possible"
```

I'd strongly recommend having it return a missing value `NA` (which can be considered numeric) rather than text like `"not possible"` which is `character` class. That way `getRootVectorized(c(-1, 4))` will work nicely and return an `NA` and  a number. The way it currently is, the `2` answer will be coerced to `character` class, which isn't as useful.

A more efficient approach would be to use the already-vectorized `ifelse`:

```
getRoot <- function(x) ifelse(x < 0, NA, sqrt(x))
```

Though `sqrt` essentially already does this, returning `NaN` (not a number) for inputs less than 0... so you don't really need another function at all.

Answer (score 1):

A literal vectorisation of your code would be:

```
getRootVectorized <- function(x){
    return(ifelse(x<0,
                  "not possible",
                   sqrt(abs(x))))
                   #The abs is added to surpress warnings for negative values
}
```

However this would be a bad idea because all elements of a vector have to be the same type, so if one number is negative the values of the positive results get converted to characters. That's why `NaN` is used for this in the standard `sqrt()` function, which is already vectorised, and I'd urge you to use the built in function, unless this is just a toy example for learning.

e.g

```
getRootVectorized(c(-1,1))
#[1] "not possible" "1"
```

is a different type to:

```
getRootVectorized(c(1,1))
#[1] 1 1
```

whereas:

```
sqrt(c(-1, 1))
#[1] NaN 1
```

and

```
sqrt(c(1, 1))
#[1] 1 1
```

return the same type

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize scalar functions with the `base` function `Vectorize`

```
getrootVectorized <- Vectorize(getRootNotVectorized)
getrootVectorized(c(-1, -4))
[1] "not possible" "not possible"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

R is a vectorised language, so you can do:

```
ifelse(vec_to_sqrt > 0, as.character(sqrt(vec_to_sqrt)), "not possible")
```

Data:

```
vec_to_sqrt <- rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!